# How to upload existing asp.net site to Windows Azure?

Tags: mysql, azure

trying to migrate my **existing asp.net website** which is using **mysql** to **Windows Azure**.

I have a few questions

- How do i **host my existing asp.net application in Windows Azure?**

  Any good links to recommend for a beginner?
- Is it a must to create a windows azure application in order to host my existing website in Azure?
- Is it true that **mysql** will cost $0.12 an hour **per web role**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hosting asp.net applications in Windows Azure is a broad subject.  I suggest starting with  a tutorial such as this one for initial intro: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment-to-windows-azure/walkthrough-hosting-an-aspnet-mvc-application-on-windows-azure
2. Simplest would be to add your existing ASP.NET project as a Web Role to a new Azure project.  (Tutorial link above explains how this can be done)
3. MySQL is not supported in Windows Azure at this time.  I suggest either switching to SQL Azure (prices [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/sql-azure/)) or you will need to host MySQL instance elsewhere and connect to it from Azure servers (not recommended due to latency).  Installing MySQL on a Windows Azure instances is totally not recommended, since those instances are stateless and Azure can choose to re-image them at any time.  (Unless you have a read-only MySQL database and have a way to auto-install it via a setup script)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind, ASP.NET Sites are not supported, it has to be an application.  You can see this link for how to convert to an application if needed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx